# Why is the brush pane locked?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, blend

In both visual studio 2012 and blend 4, I have managed to do something to "lock" the brush pane.  It is surrounded with a yellow border, like it is bound.  This occurs on every user control, and every object with a brush property, as far as I can tell.  I created a new user control, added a rectangle, no binding whatsoever, and the brush pane was yellow and locked.

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="PlayCentralPrototype.Sandbox"
    x:Name="Window"
    Width="1000" Height="880">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF123456" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="125"     Margin="99,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: A screenshot of the issue might help.

Comment: Does each brush option have the little yellow square next to it also to suggest the property for `Fill` `Stroke` etc is data bound? Next I would ask, is what happens if you put a `Style="{x:Null}"` on your `Rectangle` (in case for some reason it's inheriting a global template from somewhere for some reason that does have those properties bound with `Rectangle` as the `TargetType`.)

Comment: Still waiting for this bug to show itself again

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your controls are not locked. (I know you probably have).

Second, using attributes syntax only gives you access to one of the brush classes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush.aspx

Try using Object Element Syntax

```
<Rectangle Width="75" Height="75">
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
  </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Included is a link from MSDN that gives a walkthrough of the code from beginning to end.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752299.aspx

Blend for Visual Studio 2012
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj129478.aspx

The other solution to try is uninstalling and removing all visual studio installs and associated installs and reinstalling with all required SDK, C++ Redistributable, etc. Double checking that you have everything. I have found VS to be problematic when upgrading.

Please let me know if this solves your difficulties.